# Large Key Value Store in Sql Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

We want to store a large key-value pair set in Sql Azure (approx. 50GB) consisting of an MD5 hash key and an int value.
The table will be not be written to after it has been populated and often queried. Queries will be for multiple keys ranging from between 6 and 5000 items at a time.
Are there any best practices that we should follow, for example: is it okay to query using IN, should be chunk larger queries into smaller sections? Anything else we should be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

How complex will be your queries? Maybe you can consider alternatives to SQL server.

Azure storage tables - noSQL key-value storage great for storage of large amount of data, pretty fast for queries by partition key and row key, and cheap comparing to SQL. If you can make good partitioning and retrieve data (6-5000 items) as whole partitions, you are done. See comparision to SQL : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj553018.aspx

DocumentDB - another non-structured noSQL storage, more indexed and query-friendly than Azure Tables. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/documentdb/

Comment: The queries will be very simple: e.g. select key, value from keyvalue where key in (...). The is speed rather than cost. It will be impossible to make sure a select only hits one partition though.

Comment: Are these groups (key IN clause) exclusive? Or can 1 entity be part of multiple of groups? If they are exclusive, they are clear option for partition keys in Azure Tables

Comment: The previous comment says that "It will be impossible to make sure a select only hits one partition". e.g. Select 1: select where key in (A, B, C) , Select 2: select where key in (B, C, D), Select 3: select where key in (Z, A, B). Obviously A, B... etc are MD5 hashes.

Comment: We also have looked at noSQL storage before. We found these problems: i) MongoDb blows up if the index is bigger than memory. This is one large table so the index becomes way too large for memory. This was 1 year ago, so maybe things have improved. ii) Redis just wasn't memory efficient enough as keys and values had to be strings rather than  byte array, or int so we soon blew the memory on even a large Redis cache.

Comment: @chrisb Has been quite some time, but have you found a/the solution and what were your observations around it?